# how to make fixed element size on small screen as well as in the TV bigger screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

Hi Community please i have problem about responsiveness it's really challenging for me and i have searched all around the web with no result , problem is how to make an element not responsive to all different screen sizes, example i have image and i want it to be not responsive i have try width and height with cm or mm but it's not solving the problem when i implement this image on TV it's going bigger so i want is to be the seem 1cm as i mesure it with the role and the TV , there is any guide to solve this ! i hope that i'm not wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way of doing this. The only possible soloution would be to scale everything based on the screen size.

Comment: thank you very much for your response i think i have to do it with javascript functionnality just i have to find how much the element scale in the diffrent screen sizes ! i don't know  it's my first challenge in my first job :(

Comment: so you mean the scale in pixels of an element? if so maybe try
document.getElementById("ID_of_flement").clientWidth;
document.getElementById("ID_of_flement").clientHeight;
in javascript.
And also if its your fist job dont feel bad aking a coworker for help.